# Why do my "steel ice cubes" have water in them?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, material-science, phase-transition, ice

I recently bought steel ice cubes. A better name is probably "steel cubes with unidentified liquid" which I presume is water. When I opened the package I was quite surprised that they contained some liquid. I thought it was going to be a solid cube of steel. This made me think how do steel cubes compare to plastic cubes filled with water (or regular ice cubes)?

Volume of cube: $V=(2\ \mathrm{cm})^3=8\cdot10^{-6}\mathrm{m^3}$
Specific heat capacity of ice $C_i=2090\left[\mathrm{\frac{J}{kg ^\circ C}}\right]$
Specific heat capacity of steel $C_s=466\left[\mathrm{\frac{J}{kg ^\circ C}}\right]$
Density of ice $\rho_i=917 \left[\mathrm{\frac{kg}{m^3}}\right]$
Density of steel $\rho_s=7750 \left[\mathrm{\frac{kg}{m^3}}\right]$

I used the lower boundary for density of steel (from source).

Ice cubes:
Heat capacity $C=\rho_i\cdot V \cdot C_i \approx 15.33\left[\mathrm{\frac{J}{^\circ C}}\right]$

Steel cubes:
Heat capacity $C=\rho_s\cdot V \cdot C_s \approx  28.89\left[\mathrm{\frac{J}{^\circ C}}\right]$

Even though I used the lower boundary for the density of steel it still has more heat capacity than ice. From this it seems to make most sense to produce cubes of solid steel since it would cool your drink more.

Why do my steel cubes (used for cooling drinks) contain (presumably) water?

Could it be that solid steel cubes transfer their heat too quickly? Hence manufacturers add water inside which does lower the heat capacity but make the cubes cool for a longer time period? Or am I interpreting the results from my calculations wrongly? Or maybe my calculations are wrong?

Sources where I get values:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steel
[https://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~rwest/wikispeedia/wpcd/wp/i/Ice.htm](https://www.cs.mcgill.ca/%7Erwest/wikispeedia/wpcd/wp/i/Ice.htm)
https://gchem.cm.utexas.edu/data/section2.php?target=heat-capacities.php

Comment: Steel ice cubes. I hope you don't have any friends who habitually much their ice.

Comment: ... munch (I believe is what is meant).

Comment: I think you are expecting steel to be better at heat storage than water.   Actually, water is the best heat storage material known by volume.  So your math is off.  By [volumetric heat capacity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volumetric_heat_capacity), water beats steel (though steel is #2 among common materials).  See [table here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_specific_heat_capacities)

Comment: These sound like a vast improvement on the earlier whisky stones, that were/are solid steel

Comment: I wonder how you can tell they have liquid in them, if they are made of steel which is not transparent?

Comment: @user253751 not unrelated, I wonder the the water was put in there and sealed

Comment: @ChrisH: I have whiskey stones actually made of stone (and completely useless)

Comment: @user253751 There must be air inside to allow space for the water to expand when it freezes. So OP must be able to hear the water when he shakes the cubes.

Comment: @WoJ all the solid ones are useless, but some are more decorative than others

Comment: @NeilBartlett is right. One can hear and feel some liquid within the cubes by shaking them. And I totally agree with the reason for them not being completely filled (which then would probably make the liquid within not be noticed) is that it needs space for when it expands. I'm not sure but I believe that water is only one of a few liquids that expand when cooled so then one can make a qualified guess that the liquid inside is water. Also it is stated at the backside of the package that they contain liquid but they do not specify what type of liquid.

Comment: It's possible that it's a saline solution instead of pure water.  That would depress the freezing point (and increase cooling capacity) while not adding very much cost.  Some electric ice cream makers use saline solutions, though they do need to actually *freeze* the liquid they're in contact with rather than just cool it, so cooling capacity is more of a concern for them.

Comment: I agree that, on the optimistic assumption that the manufacturer wanted these cubes to be useful, the fluid is something other than plain water.  Maybe salinated, or maybe some nontoxic antifreeze with a higher heat capacity than water.   OTOH, gimmicks like these may contain plain water, but boast that warming & melting won't dilute your drink.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Your link actually confirms what the OP has calculated, that ice has a *lower* volumetric heat capacity than steel. It's not a fault of the math, you are talking about water and they are talking about ice, though this point is somewhat obsoleted by the accepted answer.

Comment: @Rodney but when you add in the heat of fusion (solid to liquid), water still wins, unless you are trying to keep your drink below 0 Degrees Celsius, which I heartily doubt.  :-)

Comment: @Rodney yeah, I messed up.  I forgot ice would be different from liquid water.

Comment: *"The liquid insides the ice cubes are some water (74.8%), glycerol (23%), and other food-grade chemical elements (2.2%) which are non-toxic and safe."* - https://www.amazon.com/Kollea-Stainless-Reusable-Chilling-Whiskey/dp/B00EWAWZAC

Comment: Actually, there is a suspension sold for PC cooling that has greater heat capacity that plain water.  I forget the brand name but saw it a few years ago.

Comment: @Richard Some "steel ice cubes" available in AliExpress and Ebay claims that they contain a mix of water and ethanol. A proper mixed water-ethanol solution would remain liquid at home-freezer temperatures (~ -18º C). Of course a water-ethanol solution could be somewhat more toxic than a water-glycerol solution, but, in a thermodinamic-only approach, I think that it would be more efficient than water-glycerol. It seems very unprobable that a steel cube like that would be punctured in normal use. And, after all, sometimes it will be used in a beveradge that is a water-ethanol solution itself.

Comment: @JDługosz There are several solutions of water and something else that behaves better than plain water [link](https://www.electronics-cooling.com/2006/05/an-overview-of-liquid-coolants-for-electronics-cooling/). It seems that the Potassium Formate/Acetate Solution is the best (the table in the linked article lacks a volumetric heat capacity column, which should be obtained multiplying the values in the two last columns).

Comment: BTW, I looked at a product like this, and the metal cubes are filled with antifreeze!  You **do not** get the huge code storage of the phase change, nor its ability to hold at the freezing temperature.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Water thaws at 0°C.  The latent heat of fusion of water is $L_i = 344000$ J/kg, which means that to thaw the frozen water inside your cubes requires much, much more energy than you're accounting for.  Steel, on the other hand, undergoes no such phase transformation (*edit:* at comfortable drinking temperatures), and so it cannot invoke the magic of phase transformations to cool your drinks.

To put some numbers on it:  how cold would a cube of solid steel have to be to absorb as much heat as the same volume of melting ice?  We want
$$
\rho_s C_s V \Delta T = \rho_i L_i V \quad \Rightarrow \Delta T = \frac{\rho_i L_i}{\rho_s C_s} = 87.3 {}^\circ \mathrm{C}.
$$
So to match the performance of a melting ice cube at 0°C, your steel cube would have to start out at -87°C or so, which is clearly out of the range of household freezers.

Comment: Well, steel does melt. But you probably want to avoid any beverage hot enough to melt steel.

Comment: @d_b:  I dunno, I like my coffee *really* hot.

Comment: Good point! So what is the reason for steel cubes used for cooling drinks? Steel conducts the heat faster than water and having water inside makes it cool longer compared to if it were just a solid cube of steel. So there is a wanted trade off here I suppose? Or maybe the only reason is that they look more cool (pun intended).

Comment: @ludz The point of these cubes is to get the cooling effect from the melting of the ice while not diluting your drink with the melted ice (water).

Comment: @Javier I think the question is more about liquid filled steel cube vs liquid filled plastic cube, "how does steel cubes compare to plastic cubes filled with water", which I suspect steel would be better due to thermal transfer?

Comment: "The magic of [latent heat]"... do I detect another Technology Connections fan?

Comment: @NeilBartlett:  I was into latent heat before it was cool.

Comment: (But I do enjoy Tech. Connections videos)

Comment: @lutz For an example application, try looking up ‘whiskey stones’ (though those are traditionally just solid stone). There are some drinks that people will not tolerate being diluted with water from melting ice, but do not inherently care about being as cold as they would be with ice.

Comment: @phflack Steel conducts heat better than plastic, so steel-coated ice cubes will absorb heat energy faster, cooling the drink faster. But it would cool fastest with just ice, since there would be no extra layer at all to conduct heat through. Steel is a decent choice for an ice cube container, but it's really just a container that holds the melted ice and prevents the drink from being diluted - any extra layer will actually slow the drink being cooled (although the choice of steel minimizes this effect).

Comment: and if the steel cube was at -87°C then it would probably freeze some or all of the drink, which is probably not desirable. The cube filled with ice at -18 or so probably won't freeze any of the drink, but will cool the drink as a whole to the same extent.

Comment: BTW, I looked at a product like this, and the metal cubes are filled with antifreeze!  You **do not** get the huge code storage of the phase change, nor its ability to hold at the freezing temperature.   You only get the ordinary heat capacity of the water + additives.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie "But it would cool fastest with just ice" - A single steel cube fully submerges while a single ice cube stays afloat, I'm too dumb to calculate if that makes a difference. In addition one could machine a metal cube that melts the ice faster than the water would thaw by itself, it all comes down to increasing the surface area more than the barrier's insulation effect.

Comment: @user3819867 I imagine the sink vs float aspect won't make much difference - either way, there is one face of the cube that is basically useless for heat transfer. With a floating cube it's the top face, with the sinking cube it's the bottom face. Only a small amount of the ice floats out of the water entirely.